# How to upload file into microsoft sql server 2012 using PHP form file upload?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

I have never uploaded a file into a database before using a HTML upload form so not sure how to do it. I have started to modify how I would normally upload text data below though I am not sure what I am doing wrong or where to go from here. I suspect the issue might be `VALUES ('".trimText` needs to be adapted for files?

In my PHP form I have this code to accept a file (jpeg, doc etc):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" data-field-name="UploadCertificate"> 
    <label class="control-label col-md-12" style="padding-left:0px !important;">Upload Certificate*</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="UploadCertificate">
    <input name ="UploadCertificate" id="UploadCertificate" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());"/>
Browse
    </label>
    <div class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></div>
</div>
```

Then I am not sure how to insert this into my database. This is the code I used to create the database field so I am not sure if that is correct or not:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubmissionsTBL](
[UploadCertificate]  VARBINARY(MAX) NULL)
```

Then in my PHP submit file I have this code:

```
<?php    
$UploadCertificate=$_POST["UploadCertificate"];
$query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SubmissionsTBL] (
[UploadCertificate] )
VALUES
   ('".trimText($UploadCertificate)."')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do **not** use string concatenation to generate SQL!

Comment: What database library are you using? `mssql`, `odbc`, `sqlsrv` or `PDO`?

Comment: I am using sqlsrv  . What do you mean by string concatenation sorry I am only new to this?